# Python standard logger instead of twistd logger

Tags: python-2.7, logging, twisted, twistd

I'm trying to daemonize a simple Twisted application which uses Python2.7 standard library logger.

Here is the setup :

***Python application file (run.py) :***

```
import logging
import logging.config
from twisted.internet import reactor

import conf

def main():
    logging.config.dictConfig(conf.LOGGERCONF)
    logger = logging.getLogger(conf.LOGGERNAME)
    logger.debug('Starting the reactor...')
    reactor.callWhenRunning(lambda: logger.info('Reactor started'))
    reactor.run()

main()
```

***Twistd application file (daemon.tac) :***

```
from twisted.application.service import Application
from twisted.python.log import PythonLoggingObserver
from twisted.python.log import ILogObserver

application = Application('run')
application.setComponent(ILogObserver, PythonLoggingObserver().emit)
```

***Log observer file (daemonlog.py) :***

```
from twisted.python import log

def logger():
    return log.PythonLoggingObserver().emit
```

Launching the application with :

```
python run.py
```

everything works fine and log messages are correctly filed and displayed (according to the logger configuration).

Trying to daemonize with :

```
twistd -y daemon.tac --logger=daemonlog.logger
```

The daemon starts fine, I can see the twistd.pid file created (with the correct pid number), the daemon running in the ps -ef command results, but I can't see any log files (neither twistd.log or log file as created by the application when it is started normally without twistd).

In the end, I would like to use only Python's standard library logger and kind of "by-passing" twistd logger.

I'm probably missing something or misundertsanding and any help would be appreciated.